# SSRS PDF improper text placement when printed

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am having an issue with PDF files that are generated from SSRS 'scooting' up the bottom textbox when printed. I have verified that all page dimensions, margins, and so forth are setup appropriately, and within the PDF the text is being displayed at the immediate end of the page like it should be. However, when I go to print, the text is being placed about 1cm higher than it should be.

Here are the page properties:

[image: Page Properties]

The table placement properties (notice the location and size equals 11in, the size of the page):

[image: Table Properties]

Bottom half of the PDF file displaying the text at the correct location:

[image: Page Cutoff]

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you go to print dialog box set `Page Scaling` to `None`

Comment: 1. Also make sure your report margins are `0in, 0in, 0in, 0in` I don't think `,,,` is valid. 2. Can you also share Body dimensions.

Comment: I updated the margins to `0in` across the board and still no luck. The Body dimensions are also `8.5in x 11in` just like the Report dimensions.

I have also printed on four printers of varying types and brands thinking perhaps this was at the fault of the hardware, but I did not produce any successful results.